# Python 2.7 web-scraping from a LOG IN website

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, web

I want to web-scraping from a https website, where i have to login to get the informations.

Here my (first part of) code:

```js
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

url = 'https://www.opten.hu/'
values = {'user': 'MYUSERNAME',
          'password': 'MYPASSWORD'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)

params = {'Category': 6, 'deltreeid': 6, 'do': 'Delete Tree'}
url = 'https://www.opten.hu/cegtar/cegkivonat/0910000511'

result = requests.get(url, data=params, cookies=r.cookies)

print result
```

If I run it, and print the result i get "Response [200]", so its oke, the server successfully answered the http request.

After i want to navigate an other menu item on this website, where i can find the valuable informations for me. (called url)

How can i scrape this page, what i am wrong in my code?

```js
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

url = 'https://www.opten.hu/'
values = {'user': 'MYUSERNAME',
          'password': 'MYPASSWORD'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)

params = {'Category': 6, 'deltreeid': 6, 'do': 'Delete Tree'}
url = 'https://www.opten.hu/cegtar/cegkivonat/0910000511'

result = requests.get(url, data=params, cookies=r.cookies)

print result

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print soup
```

Comment: Are you getting any error with that?

Comment: No. I just get the HTML code on this webpage, but i can't see the valuable information, because the system is step out (i see at the html url that im not log in..)

Comment: You are posting your credentials to wrong url. You should post those to `https://www.opten.hu/ousers/loginuser`

Comment: I corrected it, but nothing changed. I think there is a problem in the second part of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `urllib2` to read the content. It will make another request to the url to get the data but will not use the cookies you got in the previous request.

Try the following code. I have used `requests.Session` to persist the cookies and you don't need `urllib2` now.

```
# Author: Swapnil Mahajan
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb

url = 'https://www.opten.hu/ousers/loginuser'
values = {'user': 'MYUSERNAME',
          'password': 'MYPASSWORD'}

session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(url, data=values)

params = {'Category': 6, 'deltreeid': 6, 'do': 'Delete Tree'}
url = 'https://www.opten.hu/cegtar/cegkivonat/0910000511'

result = session.get(url, data=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")
print soup
```

Comment: Mmmm, maybe i have to verify that i am not a robot?!

Comment: I refill this code : "br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)"

.But nothing changed, still now loggin

Comment: Or if i try with another way, i get this message : 

"You rode slowly our system, the reasons of which the successors may be:  exceeded the time constraint of the working process.
The concurrent users' number reached the maximum defined in the contract."

Comment: With my solution, what is the issue? What does the page return?

Comment: It is return with the "main page" without log in.

Comment: I might be able to help if you provide the credentials.

Comment: I cant give you the username and the password.
The problem is that the system is kick me from the server.

Comment: Ok. Then do observe if some other fields are also getting sent to that page.